# Oracle network issue detection using its views

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, database-connection

Is there any oracle view which confirm network issue at a given interval of time? I suspect there is a column in active_session_history view which give info about this.

Comment: What do you mean, "network issue?"

Comment: I mean queries are running slow due to network problem

Comment: How do you know it is the network vs query execution time?

Answer (score 0):

To identify network I/O caused by remote access of database files, examine the `V$IOSTAT_NETWORK` view. This view contains network I/O statistics caused by accessing files on a remote database instance, including:

Database client initiating the network I/O (such as RMAN and PLSQL)
Number of read and write operations issued
Number of kilobytes read and written
Total wait time in milliseconds for read operations
Total wait in milliseconds for write operations.

Besides, you may use utilities, such as `sar -d` (or `iostat` or `netstat`) on many UNIX systems and the administrative performance monitoring tool on Windows systems, examine I/O statistics for the entire system.

Also you may use `select a.SESSION_TYPE, a.SESSION_STATE, a.BLOCKING_SESSION_STATUS, a.* from v$active_session_history a order by a.SESSION_TYPE desc, a.SQL_EXEC_START desc` as you have pointed out.

Comment: @OldProgrammer last week, in a particular interval of time (let say 4PM to 5PM), all queries took time. For eg, a query which usually take 1 sec, took 5 mins at that time. Similarly for other queries. Next day they all became normal.

Comment: further to your info, column p1text will also help in identifying network issue, thanks